# MySQL how to get data from database order randomly

Tags: mysql

Please I am trying to get data from MySQL database in a random order but it seems to return result in duplicates.

Is there a way I can get Data in a random order while following id and not getting duplicate results.

For instance I have a database table users with 4 unique users inside.

- user1
- user2
- user3
- user4

Then I try this query

```
SELECT username from users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

I tend to receive 
User1, User2 User1

Whereas I hope to get 
User2, User1, User3 as result.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

I believe you understand and I hope this is not offtopic im grateful for any response i can get.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show SQLFiddle of the setup you have? Your query should not return same rows more than once as the `ORDER BY` mererly sorts an existing result set which does not have duplicates in it.

Comment: lol, why would you like to do this?

Comment: @andré I'm working on a project that I need to fetch posts random ly joining several tables together. But on frontend it returns the same rows twice

Comment: @slaakso   I have no idea how I can do that but I'm happy to share my real query with you

Comment: Create a sample in db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: @slaakso I will create one

Comment: Most likely your joins produce duplicate usernames in your result set and therefore the ?`ORDER BY RAND()` produces duplicates. You can avoid the duplicates with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Dear @slaakso Using the `DISTINCT` keyword works but in a situation where the query is now `LIMIT 1, 3` it still has the same issues, the first param after the limit keyword changes dynamically by theway im having problems with the JSFIDDLE my query and tables is alot

Comment: `select DISTINCT username from...` will not produce duplicates. This is what the `DISTINCT` does. If you have problems with db-fiddle, just show your actual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try DISTINCT keyword -

```
SELECT DISTINCT username
FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```